Adding .net class library reference in Visual Studio 2022
I have a Models directory which contains a file ContactModel.cs, I want to use it in my Form1.cs file in the FormApp directory. I have been going through the similar questions asked on this, but couldn't find a solution.
This is my folder structure:

Right clicking on the directories shows these options:


Important nitpick: You're not using Visual Studio Code, you're using Visual Studio 2022.  They are different product lines.  I've edited the question to account for this, but it's also something you'll want to be aware of when using these products.

You're in "folder view" in your Solution Explorer, examining the file system.  One of the icons at the top of the Solution Explorer allows you to "switch between available views".  Use that to switch to viewing your solution instead of the folders:

When viewing the solution, right-click on the project to which you want to add a reference (in this case the FormApp project) and select Add -> Project Reference.
From there, select the class library project in the solution that you want your application project to use (in this case the Models project).

when i click on the switch between available views, i have a FormApp.snl file and next to it there's a Folder View with directory icon next to it, when i right click on that there's only open option and then the same structure i asked in the question, is there a problem with how i've modified the solution structure?

@FatemehAria: Can you share an image of what you're seeing when switching views?  In my own Visual Studio 2022 instance, when switching views in the Solution Explorer, I see two options: (1) "Folder View" with a folder icon on the left and the path to the folder on the right; and (2) "MyApplication.sln" which is the solution I would choose to view.

yes, i have the same options and when i clicked on sln it worked. thank you.
